# Bootstrap grid doesnt align elements one after another

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I couldn't find out which feature blows up the grid. But this is what I want it to look like:

[image]

And this is what it looks like instead (here I've put 7 elements inside):

[image]

The code looks in its base as follows, but instead of 1 tag of `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">` it has 7 of it:

```
    <section class="pb8" id="name">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">


                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="image-tile outer-title text-center">
                        <img alt="Pic" src="source/to/img.jpg">
                        <div class="title mb16">
                            <h5 class="uppercase mb0">Title</h5>
                            <span>Subtitle</span>
                        </div>
                        <p class="lead" style="text-align: justify">
                            Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Did somebody face similar problems? Thank you

Comment: may be because of content height or image height.. your code works perfectly .

Comment: can you please post css you have written too

Comment: @SaranyaRajendran thank you! It had to do with text content height.

Comment: @saitam... Happy coding :)